# Let JavaEE Server log transaction informations

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm developing Java EE 6-applications on GlassFish for some months now, but I still have the feeling that I don't fully understand how the container managed transactions (and the implications on the persistence context) work - although I have read a lot about the underlying basics.

To get a better understanding, I would find it interesting if there was a possibility to let the Java EE-Server (for instance GlassFish) write to the log file when it starts/commits/rollbacks a transaction. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GlassFish, you can enable the logging of JTA / JTS via the admin console under **Configuration > Logging > Log Levels** using the following categories:

- JTA - javax.enterprise.resource.jta
- JTS - javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction

But the logs are pretty verbose and not that easy to read.

You might also want to activate the "monitoring" of the **Transaction Service** in the admin console via **Configuration > Monitoring**. Then, go to **Enterprise Server > Monitor > Server**.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine. You'll only need the log level **FINE** for JTA (no Monitoring is necessary) to see this:

```
FINE: TM: getTransaction: tx=null, tm=null
FINE: TM: status: Active
FINE: TM: status: NoTransaction
FINE: --Created new JavaEETransactionImpl, txId = 55
FINE: TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=55 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=null
FINE: TM: enlistComponentResources
FINE: TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=55 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=null
FINE: --In JavaEETransactionImpl.registerSynchronization, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null
```

As you can see here you can for example determine whether a new transaction was used, i.e. with @TransactionAttribute from JEE6 (at least that's what I assume). Be aware that annotation only works if called from outside the bean.

However you should raise your file size for the log rotation up to 20-100 mb because depending on your application this will write a lot of info in your logs.